# Is it possible to emit stream object through socket.io

Tags: socket.io, streaming, audio-streaming

For my app I'm streaming audio data from a raspberry-pi client to my node.js audio service through socket.io. The problem is, to process the audio, I'm piping the audio stream from client in my service to an external service. Then this external service will give the result stream audio back to my service and my service will emit it to the client.

So my application flow is like

Client ---*socket.io-stream*---> audio_service ---*stream*---> external_service

external_service --*stream*---> audio_service ---*socket.io-stream*---> client

My questions is:

1. Is it possible that when a client connected to my audio_service, my audio_service will initiate a connection to external_service and emit that connection back to the client through socket.io? This way the client will stream audio directly to the external_service by using the returned connection instead of going through audio_service.
2. If it is possible, is it also possible that even though the client stream audio directly to the external_service, it will still send the stream result back to the audio_service?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to send a stream through Socket.IO the way it is set up today.  Some folks have made some add-ons that emulate streams in the usual evented RPC way, but it isn't very efficient.

The best library I know for this is Binary.JS.  This will give you streams multiplexed over a single binary WebSocket connection.  Unfortunately, Binary.js hasn't been maintained in awhile, but it still works.